# How to create an image in opencv from a buffer that holds image in RGBA format

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I have an image in a buffer that hold an image with format of RGBA. I want to create an openCV image from it (cv::Mat), but it seems that I can not do this.

The code that I have is this:

```
cv::Mat image=cv::Mat(cvSize(Width,Height), CV_8UC4,Buffer, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP).clone();
```

The main problem is that since OpenCV is saving its images in BGRA format, and the buffer has image in RGBA format, the colours of generated image is not correct.

I know that I can convert the image to BGRA format, but is there any way that I can create an image in OpenCV that holds images in RGBA format?

Comment: But all the algorithms that get images as input do use BGRA, so its better to crate it that way.

Comment: @AnderBiguri the buffer is in rgba, so I can not create it in bgra. can I?

Comment: I am not good with openCV, but I guess you could clone it and then somehow swap the channel data, right?

Comment: @AnderBiguri You are right, I can convert it to BGRA, but my question is if I can use it without conversion.

Comment: We are looping again. My first comment meant: I you may be able to do it ( I dont know) , but if later on you want to use openCV algorithms that take images as inputs, you may not want to do it beacuse they are designed to accept BGRA. In the end its just data reodered, if everything else you do  you are aware that red is the first channel, then just use it as it is now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cvtColor` to convert the `Mat` from RGBA to BGRA. And if you will do it right after creation of the "original" `Mat` from the buffer, you need not to use `clone()`, as anyway the new buffer will be allocated for the converted image.

```
cv::Mat image=cv::Mat(cvSize(Width,Height), CV_8UC4, Buffer, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);
cv::Mat converted;
cvtColor(image, converted, CV_RGBA2BGRA);
```

Answer (score 1):

you create an image in RGBA format with your code, that's no problem.

The problem is that OpenCV assumes BGR(A) images when saving the image or using openCV methods.

Maybe you can use special libraries (png lib, jpeg lib etc) to save images directly in RGB(A) format, instead. OpenCV really is about BGR for displaying or saving the images, since no color model is assigned to the images (it's just a x bit 3/4 channel image, whatever color model is used must be maintained by the user).