# how to convert SFML image to OpenCV mat in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, image-processing, sfml

Below code is used to convert an OpenCV Mat image into SFML image. How to convert SFML image back to Mat image?

```
    cv::Mat frameBGR, frameBGRA;
    sf::Image image;
    cv::cvtColor(frameBGR, frameRGBA, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGBA);
    image.create(frameRGBA.cols, frameRGBA.rows, frameRGBA.ptr());
```

If texture or sprite can't be converted to OpenCV Mat,then is it possible to convert sf::Image to OpenGL and convert it back to cv::Mat

```
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Event event;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    texture.loadFromImage(image);
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
```

**Update:** I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854738/how-to-create-an-image-in-opencv-from-a-buffer-that-holds-image-in-rgba-format) post, but still was not able to convert.

```
    void* buffer = &image; 
    cv::Mat image_mat = cv::Mat(cvSize(500, 500),CV_8UC4, buffer, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);  
    cvtColor(image_mat, converted,CV_RGBA2BGR);
```

It crashes at below line of code (when i display image )

```
imshow("img", converted);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
cv::Mat sfml2opencv(const sf::Image& img){
    //get size from image
    cv::Size size(img.getSize().x, img.getSize().y);
    //create a mat on image memory
    cv::Mat mat(size,CV_8UC4, (void*)img.getPixelsPtr(), cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);
    //make SFML RGBA to OpenCV BGRA
    cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGRA);
    //clone mat to avoid memory editing on image memory
    return mat.clone();
}
```

Your code crashes because you try to create the cv::Mat on the memory of the sf::Image object, instead of the memory of the pixels.